# Why is my Dojo (1.3.2) Data Grid erasing my content on sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datagrid, dojo

We are using Dojo 1.3.2 at the client we are working on so we haven't had much luck finding good examples of how to use it. We have our code for our data grid properly initializing the content, but when we try to click on a header to have it sort, it removes the container for the data elements completely without repopulating the data grid.

Our code is as follows:

```
function initializeGridData(){
        dojo.require("dojo._base.lang");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");

        /*set up data store*/
        var data = {
          identifier: "id",
          items: []
        };
        var data_list = [
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Heathcliff', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 15.00, col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/05/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Quest Diag.', col4: 45.00, col5: 95.00, col6: 'Dental', col7: 'Completed'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/03/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Completed'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Edgar', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 15.00, col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Heathcliff', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Dental', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/09/2016", col2: 'Heathcliff', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Completed'},
          { col1: "05/04/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Smith', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Prescription', col7: 'Pending'},
          { col1: "05/10/2016", col2: 'Catherine', col3: 'Dr. Linton', col4: 45.00, col5: 'TBD', col6: 'Medical', col7: 'Pending'}
        ];
        var rows = 60;
        for(var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++){
            data.items.push(dojo.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
        }
        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

        /*set up layout*/
        var layout = [[
          {'name': 'Date of Service', 'field': 'col1', 'width': '100px'},
          {'name': 'Member', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '100px'},
          {'name': 'Provider', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '200px'},
          {'name': 'Total Cost', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '150px'},
          {'name': 'You Pay', 'field': 'col5', 'width': '150px'},
          {'name': 'Type', 'field': 'col6', 'width': '150px'},
          {'name': 'Status', 'field': 'col7', 'width': '150px'}
        ]];

        /*create a new grid*/
        var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            store: store,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            structure: layout,
            canSort: function(col){ return Math.abs(col) === 2 || Math.abs(col) === 1 || Math.abs(col) === 3; }
        }, document.createElement('div'));


            /*append the new grid to the div*/
        grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

        /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
        grid.startup();
    }
```

Which yields the following results:

[image: Rendered Data Grid]

Upon clicking a header, this occurs:

[image]

And inspecting the DOM, it looks like the content has been completely removed.

Would any of you have any idea as to why this is happening? Is there some sort of property we forgot to add in?

Answer (score 0):

The code here

```
    http://jsfiddle.net/bradyhouse/bnqkodup/
```

looks oddly similar and that was probably intended for an enhanced grid, not sure. Could be nuances moving the grid around in the dom, or writing custom sorting functions.

Reference to DataGrid (1.6 reference - oldest I could find quickly, but most properties should be available in 1.3.x):

```
    https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html
```

Here are some simplified jsfiddles intended for simple DataGrid API. The first is similar to the approach you have currently with some minor exceptions.

```
    http://jsfiddle.net/vijayagrawal/NNQpn/
    http://jsfiddle.net/bc7yt/11/
```

Try these and see if you have luck. Rather than trying to debug dojo, approach it from a different angle and don’t get hung up on the details.

Good luck. Hopefully no other JS is conflicting causing weirdness.